# Mathematical notation nth smallest element of a set

Tags: notation

I want to put the following in formula-form: 
"$ T_i$ should be the sum of the $ b $ smallest durations out of all durations of the predecessors of $i$ (which is the set $P_i$)"

Does a mathematical formulation exist to describe the "$n$-th smallest element of a set"?

This was my trial:

$$T_i =  \sum\limits_{n=0}^{b} \min\limits_{n}\{ t_j \mid j \in  P_i \} $$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not clear on the idea that you are trying to express.  Why not simply order the $t_j$'s in increasing order, then add up the first $b$ of them?  Or are you trying to order the $P_i$'s?  I'm quite confused...

Comment: Those are called [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Notation_and_examples). Notation, like all language, works in context. You can borrow the notation in that link, which will work for those who use it. Include its definition for those who don't.